# BarLegend with text between -1 to 1

Tags: legending

I use the following line to plot my graphic. I have defined the following function for the color of my graphic `myTemperatureMap[f_] := Blend[{{-1, Blue}, {-0.25, Lighter@LightBlue}, {-0.25, White}, {0, White}, {0.3, Yellow}, {0.6, Red}}, f];` and I use the following line to plot my graphic

```
graph2 = ListContourPlot[data,
    PlotRange -> {{-0.05, 0.05}, {-0.05, 0.05}, {-1., 1.}}, 
    ColorFunction -> myTemperatureMap, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ContourStyle -> None, Contours -> 200, 
    PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> 300, LabelingFunction -> (Style[NumberForm[#, {Infinity, 2}], Bold, Black, 12] &)]];
```

I get the following image [image]

However, I would like to see my `BarLegend` between -1 to 1 with 0 in the middle. How to change the range in my `BarLegend` ? I Tried to change `Automatic` to `{"myTemperatureMap",{-1,1}}` in `BarLegend` but it is not working...

Comment: does `BarLegend[{Automatic, {-1, 1}}, LegendMarkerSize -> 300]` work?

Comment: No, there is no difference

Comment: it works in v9, it doesn't in v11.

Comment: `BarLegend[{myTemperatureMap[#] &, {-1, 1}}, LegendMarkerSize -> 300]` works v11 too.

Comment: I use v11. Last one works. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = Table[{#, #2, .8 Sin[# ] Cos[#2]} & @@ RandomReal[{-3, 3}, 2], {1000}];

graph2 = ListContourPlot[data, ColorFunction -> myTemperatureMap, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ContourStyle -> None,  Contours -> 200, 
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> 300]]
```

[image]

Changing `BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> 300]` to

```
BarLegend[{myTemperatureMap[#]& , {-1,1}} , LegendMarkerSize -> 300]
```

we get

[image]